# dataframe groupby operations

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do operations in rows with the same category.
Suppose that I have the following dataframe

```
  |  Category  |    course  |  2010  |  2011  |  2012  |
------------------------------------------------------------
0 |      A     |    Math    |   981  |   21   |  9817  |
1 |      A     |   English  |   14   |  1610  |  11487 |
2 |      A     |   History  | 22.74  |   15   |  12256 |
3 |      B     |    Math    |   NaN  |   NaN  |  9817  |
4 |      B     |   English  |   NaN  |  1610  |   11   |
5 |      B     |   History  | 22.74  |   NaN  |   25   |
```

and I would like to get the operation below.

```
  |  Category  |    course  |  2010  |  2011  |  2012  |
------------------------------------------------------------
0 |      A     |    NEW     |   XXX  |   XXX  |   XXX  |
1 |      B     |    NEW     |   XXX  |   XXX  |   XXX  |
```

Where NEW is the result of the following operation:
(MATH + English) * History/100
For each new cell (XXX) in the years columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the DataFrame by `Category` and aggregate the value for each year by the provided formula. You can access the according values of each column by setting  `course` as index beforehand.

```
def aggregate_courses(row):
    return (row["Math"] + row["English"]) * row["History"] / 100

df.set_index("course").groupby("Category").aggregate(aggregate_courses).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Category  2010     2011    2012
0   A         226.263  244.65  2611018.24
1   B         NaN      NaN     2457.0
```

Somehow the `course` column got lost. If you need it back you can put it back again.

```
result["course"] = "NEW"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
m=df['course'].isin(['Math','English'])#Mask
g=df[m].groupby('Category').sum()#dataframe with the summation of math and english
h=df[~m].drop('course',1).groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x/100).fillna(0)#dataframe with history
df3=pd.DataFrame(g.values*h.values, columns=g.columns, index=g.index)#element to element multiplication of dfs

    

             2010    2011        2012
Category                             
A         226.263  244.65  2611018.24
B           0.000    0.00     2457.00
```

Comment: Downvoter, why did you down vote and this answer is faster than the accepted?